# Change an instance of a parent class into a child class

Tags: ruby, class

In the example below, I have `Pet` class that is a child of the `Dog` class. I'd like to be able to convert my instances of `Dog` into `Pet`.

```
class Dog
  def bark
    "Wof!"
  end
  attr_accessor :age
end


class Pet < Dog
  attr_accessor :name
end


white_dog = Dog.new
puts white_dog.class  # => Pet
puts white_dog.bark   # => Wof!
white_dog.age = 5
```

Let's say I've just adopted the dog. He's my pet and shoud have a name.
I want to change `white_dog` from the `Dog` class to the `Pet` class so I get this:

```
puts white_dog.class          # => Pet
puts white_dog.bark           # => Wof!
puts white_dog.age = 5        # => 5
puts white_dog.name = "Rex"   # => Rex
```

Is it possible to do that without using `Pet.new` and passing all the instance variables like `@age`?

Comment: You'd have to make Pet a module instead of a class if you want to use it as a mixin.

Comment: Sounds interesting, how would that be?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can do what you want to do, but I cannot offer a proof. If you still need to create an instance of `Pets` whose instance variables have the same values as those of a given instance of `Dog`, here is a way to at least automate the copying of the values of the instance variables.

**Code**

```
def copy_instance_variables(parent, child)
  parent.instance_variables.each { |v| 
  child.instance_variable_set(v, parent.instance_variable_get(v)) }
end
```

**Example**

```
class Dog
  def favorites(food, toy)
    @food = food
    @toy = toy
  end
end

fifi = Dog.new
  #=> #<Dog:0x00000102089488>
fifi.favorites('roast beef', 'frisbee')
  #=> "frisbee"

class Pet < Dog
end

mimi = Pet.new
  #=> #<Pet:0x0000010207bb08>

copy_instance_variables(fifi, mimi)
  #=> [:@food, :@toy]

mimi
  #=> #<Pet:0x0000010207bb08 @food="roast beef", @toy="frisbee">
```

Incidentally, it's a little unusual for `Pet` to be a subclass of `Dog`; one would expect it to be the other way around.

**Addendum**

Don't be too hard on Ruby for not providing everything you might want, but on the other hand anyone can make a case to the Ruby monks to add something new.

The upside is that since Ruby has open classes, you can always add new methods to do what you want. Here, you want to "convert" an instance of a class to an instance of a subclass.  Here's an example of how you might do that by adding a method:

```
copy_instance_to_subclass(subclass)
```

to the class `Object`. This method would be used to create an instance of the given subclass and copy the values of instance variables and class instance variables from `self`, the Parent class instance.  This only works, however, when neither the parent nor child class has an `initialize` method. (Think about that. It wouldn't make sense to create an instance of a class without invoking `initialize` when it is present.) As well, there may be other limitations I haven't considered.

If `A` is the parent class and `AA` the subclass, this is to be invoked:

```
a = A.new
aa = a.copy_instance_to_subclass(AA)
```

Once you've copied the instance, you can set the variable `a` to something else (`nil` or `aa`, say), thereby abandoning it. That tells the garbage collector it can be hauled to the dump.

*Code*

```
class Object
  def copy_instance_to_subclass(subclass)
    isub = subclass.send :new 
    # copy values of instance variables
    instance_variables.each { |v| 
      isub.instance_variable_set(v, instance_variable_get(v)) }
    # copy values of class instance variables
    self.class.instance_variables.each { |v| 
      subclass.instance_variable_set(v, self.class.instance_variable_get(v)) }
    isub
  end
end
```

*Example*

```
class A
  @@a  = 0
  @b   = 1
  def set_vars
    @c = 2
    @d = 3
  end
end

class AA < A
  def show_cv
    puts "@@a = #{@@a}"
  end
end

a = A.new
  #=> #<A:0x000001012b8020>
a.set_vars
  #=> 3
aa = a.copy_instance_to_subclass(AA)
  #=> #<AA:0x000001012c82b8 @c=2, @d=3>
```

*Check instance variables*

Let's confirm `aa`'s and `AA`'s instance variables have the correct values. First, it useful to make a small helper method:

```
def display_ivs(obj)
  obj.instance_variables.each { |v| puts "#{v} = #{obj.instance_variable_get(v)}" }
end

display_ivs(aa)
@c = 2
@d = 3
  #=> [:@c, :@d]
```

*Check class instance variables*

```
display_ivs(AA)
@b = 1
  #=> [:@b]
```

*Confirm the class variable is visible*

```
aa.show_cv
  # @@a = 0
```

Comment: I was asking if it was possible not to use `Pet.new`

Comment: Victor, see my edit of the first paragraph. I had the impression that you were now using `Pet.new` and manually copying the values of the instance variables, and wondering if you could instead just change the `Dog` object's class. If your question was just hypothetical, let me know and I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if the answer to my question is no, I guess your solution is the best workaround. But I'm a bit disappointed with Ruby, I thought it would have something more elegant.

Comment: @Victor: "I'm a bit disappointed with ruby" - hah, find me another language that can do this. :) This is not how OOP works.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the class of an object in Ruby.

Smalltalk has the `become:` method, which lets one object become another object, and since any object can `become:` any other object, the new object could theoretically have a different class. But even in this extreme case, you don't change the class of an *existing* object, you change an object into a *different* object with a (potentially) different class.